# Python: detect changes in a subclass

Tags: python-3.x, class, subclass

Let's consider the following example:

```
class SubClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._param = None

    @property
    def param(self):
        print('read param')
        return self._param

    @param.setter
    def param(self, value):
        print('set param')
        self._param = value


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = SubClass()

    @property
    def var(self):
        print('read var')
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        print('set var')
        self._var = value
```

If I do:

```
cls = MainClass()
cls.var.param = 3
```

I obtain:

```
'read var'
'set param'
```

How can I make `MainClass` aware that `var.param` has changed?

Useful additional info: consider that in my actual code `param` is not a scalar but an array with hundreds of elements, so I would like to avoid to create a copy and then just compare them. Moreover, `param` and `var` are not the only properties.

Comment: why do you need this in the first place? looks like an XY problem to me

Comment: to make it simple, because I need to make some operations in ```MainClass``` but only if ```var.param``` has changed.

Comment: You could consider using an observer class to track changes. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878220/looking-for-a-solution-to-detect-value-change-in-class-attribute-with-a-list-and

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pass a method from `MainClass` as an argument when instantiating `SubClass`, and have `SubClass` call it whenever it changes a variable:

```
class SubClass:
    def __init__(self, changed):
        self._param = None
        self.changed = changed

    @property
    def param(self):
        print('read param')
        return self._param

    @param.setter
    def param(self, value):
        print('set param')
        self._param = value
        self.changed('param')


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = SubClass(self.changed)
    
    def changed(self, name):
        print("Subclass changed: ", name, getattr(self._var, name))

    @property
    def var(self):
        print('read var')
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        print('set var')
        self._var = value


m = MainClass()
m.var.param = 'test'
```